# Can I update specific field value in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing

I want to update count field in the following doc for example. Please help

```
{
        "_index" : "test-object",
        "_type" : "data",
        "_id" : "2.5.179963",
        "_score" : 10.039009,
        "_source" : {
          "object_id" : "2.5.179963",
          "block_time" : "2022-04-09T13:16:32",
          "block_number" : 46975476,
          "parent" : "1.2.162932",
          "field_type" : "1.3.2",
          "count" : 57000,
          "maintenance_flag" : false
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) as

```
POST <your-index>/_update/<your-doc-id>
{
    "doc": {
        "count": "" // provide the value which you want to update
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working

"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_update]"}]

Elasticsearch version: 6.7.2

Comment: @Subo which Elasticsearch version you are using?

Comment: Version is 6.7.2

Comment: @Subo you need to pass `_doc` in the URL, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document doc for Elasticsearch 6.8